# Why ng-repeate object not getting updated?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is the function which load listings from server. Initially listings are displayed but when gets null response on applying filter, it still shows previous result and not clearing previous listings.

```
 $scope.browseListing = function (strURL) {
        $scope.CurrentTab = strURL;
        $scope.getURL(strURL);
        $http.post($scope.URL)
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data != 'null') {
                        $scope.Data = response.data;
                        $scope.TotalListingCount = $scope.Data.length;                                            
                        $window.alert('Result is not null');
                    }
                    else {
                        $scope.TotalListingCount = '0';
                        $window.alert('Result is null');
                        $scope.Data = [];
                    }
                }, function (response) {
                    $log.info(response);
                });
    };
```

**Edited**

[image]

How do I solve this so that on empty response previous listings gets cleared and shows no listings?

Comment: update your respective html markup and json data retrieved from the server

Comment: @Aravind, do I need to show/hide ng-repeate as per response?

Comment: Are you getting "Result is null" alert when there is no data ?

Comment: Yes, alert popups when returns null response..

Comment: @jmd not exactly depends on solution u are looking for. if there is some HTML we can atleast try to find where is the issue.

Comment: had you try with `$scope.$apply()`??

Comment: @RameshRajendran, Yes I also tried that but got an error `Error: $rootScope:inprog
Action Already In Progress`

Comment: Check the condition `if(!$scope.$$phase)` before Apply scope which I have already update in my answer

Comment: `$scope.CurrentTab = strURL;$scope.getURL(strURL);$http.post($scope.URL)`. Are you sure this is supposed to work like this ? Add the definition of getUrl function please, to be sure.

Comment: @Walfrat, Yes can debug server code when call made from angular code. From server null response returned to http request.

Answer (score 1):

May be your scope does not update. Please try this below ( it's not 100% good approach, But at this time you can solve your issue)

```
 if(!$scope.$$phase) {
  $scope.$apply(
         $scope.Data = [];
       );
  }    
   $scope.TotalListingCount = '0';
   $window.alert('Result is null');
```

- and please check your console having any error.

**Update :** 
try another way like this (declare empty object globally)

```
    .then(function (response) {
                            $scope.TotalListingCount = '0';
                            $scope.Data = [];
                        if (response.data != 'null') {
                            $scope.Data = response.data;
                         $scope.TotalListingCount = $scope.Data.length;                                             
                            $window.alert('Result is not null');
                        }
                        else {
                                $window.alert('Result is null');
                              }
                    }
```

> It's does not works well, then please share your filter code. Bcs the problem should be there.

Comment: Error in console, `Error: $rootScope:inprog
Action Already In Progress`

Comment: Delete your cache.

Comment: @Ramesh Rajendran, I also tried for `!$scope.$$phase`. After adding `$$phase` no error in console but problem is still there.

Comment: Can you show me your response JSON, while you getting null data?

Comment: @RameshRajendran, I have update question with null response.

Comment: The issue is in the filter most definitely.

Comment: @stormec56, I have updated question with ng-repeat and filter code.

Comment: I'm guessing you have assigned controller in the parent?

Comment: @stormec56, added more details in ng-repeat with controller. Is there any error in code while displaying listings.?

Comment: @RameshRajendran, Yes I have tried that and it alerts as per response status but not updating UI when null response.

Comment: Just remove your filter and check.

Comment: @RameshRajendran, checked after removing filters but still not working..

Comment: change `$scope.Data = null;`  instead of `$scope.Data = [];`

Answer (score 0):

The following create new scopes, and inherit prototypically: `ng-repeat`, `ng-include`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-controller`, `directive` with `scope: true`, `directive` with `transclude: true`.

So, use `$parent` with `'ng-repeate' to reference to parent scope instead of using newly created scope by`ng-repeat` as-

`<tr ng-repeat="listing in $parent.Data | orderBy : sortColumn : SortDirection">`

After adding `$parent` in `ng-repeat` to scope property in `UI` it updates `UI` as per changes.

[Here is full description of scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)